# With a 80 meter long fence, a trapezoid shaped field wants to be created.

Tags: geometry

With a 80 meter long fence, a trapezoid shaped field wants to be created based on floor. What's the biggest area of that shape?

The problem is i can't imagine the shape. Is it gonna be something like that:
[image: Shape]

And what am i gonna use? Integral?

Comment: A trapezoid is a plane figure, and you seem to be drawing a solid.  Note that the questions asks for area, not volume.  https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/trapezoid.html

Comment: You want $2$D, not $3$D.

Comment: Isosceles trapezoid*

Comment: Hmm but question says "An area wants to be created" So if the shape is 2D wouldn't that be a too easy question?

Comment: Let me ask my teacher and i'm gonna come inform you.

Comment: If we are given an Isosceles trapezoid, with small base $a$, long base $b$, and sides $c$, would you be able to construct the formula for the area in terms of $a,b,c$? This will then be the formula you want to maximize under the constraints that $a,b,c \gt 0$ and $a+b+2c = 80$

Comment: Thank you but this question asked in my calculus-2 final exam. And i think it'll be solved in different ways.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question some time ago, where the fence is to be put against the wall. You do need Calculus to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes i learned it and it'll be 2d. I need  calculus yes but by using what?

Comment: He wants me to use multivariable function. Then i think i'll use @WaveX's function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of calculus. Consider a trapezoid with different bases $a$ and $b$: a rectangle with the same height and the other two sides equal to $(a+b)/2$ has the same area and a shorter perimeter. Hence any trapezoid with bases $a\ne b$ has a smaller area than a rectangle with the same perimeter and two opposite sides equal to $(a+b)/2$.

To find maximum area we can then confine ourselves to rectangles, and it is a well known result that among all rectangles with the same perimeter the square has the largest area. The answer is then: build a square field with a side of $20\ $m.